# How does require 'digest/md5' works?

Tags: ruby, md5, require, digest

```
require 'digest/md5'       # => true
Digest::Md5.hexdigest('')  # => "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
```

Which file does this require use? Is an actual file being required? Or is it required programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (sorta) explained in the [documentation for `Kernel#require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

> #### require(name) → true or false
>
> Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if
>   the feature is already loaded.
>
> If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be
>   searched for in the directories listed in `$LOAD_PATH` (`$:`).
>
> If the filename has the extension “.rb”, it is loaded as a source file; if
>   the extension is “.so”, “.o”, or “.dll”, or the default shared library
>   extension on the current platform, Ruby loads the shared library as a Ruby
>   extension.  Otherwise, Ruby tries adding “.rb”, “.so”, and so on to the
>   name until found.  If the file named cannot be found, a LoadError will be raised.

By default `$LOAD_PATH` will include the directories where Ruby's standard library lives. Director*ies*, plural, because native (compiled binary) modules in the standard library live in a different directory than pure-Ruby modules.

Digest is actually a great example because some of its files are native and others are Ruby.

On my Mac `$LOAD_PATH` includes (among others) these two directories (truncated for readability):

1. `.../usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0`
2. `.../usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15`

The former is where pure-Ruby modules live and the latter is where native modules live.

So when I do `require 'digest/md5'` Ruby first looks in `.../usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/` for a directory named `digest/`, and upon finding it, for a file in it named `md5.rb`. It doesn't find it, so it looks for `md5.bundle`. Why `.bundle` and not `.so` or `.o`? Because that's the "default shared library extension" that Ruby was configured with when it was compiled for OS X. Go figure.

Ruby doesn't find it there, so next it looks in `.../usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/digest/`. There's no `md5.rb` there, but there *is* an `md5.bundle`, so Ruby loads it.

Answer (score 1):

It loads a C-extension that can be found in Ruby's source dir - [ruby/ext/digest/md5/](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/ruby_2_2/ext/digest/md5)

Answer (score 1):

It's one of Ruby's standard libraries (stdlib), which means that it's available in pretty much every implementation of Ruby. It does, in fact, load a file. But it's a file that was copied to your computer when you installed Ruby and is pretty much always going to be available to you. Another good example of a standard library is `DateTime`.

One thing that confused me a lot when I started learning Ruby and Rails was that Rails requires a fair number of Ruby's standard libraries for you. So it's good to be aware of what's actually going on under the hood.